# Creating a stacked budget Vs Actual chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to use chartJS to create a stacked budget with an actual vs budgeted amount.

So I am aiming to create something like this.

[image: Stacked]

I have gotten this far with it.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chartjs-7"), {
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": ["Petrol", "Food", "Kids Clubs", "Alcohol"],
    "datasets": [{
      "label": "Actual Spend",
      "data": [70, 100, 20, 29],
      "borderColor": "rgb(63, 191, 63)",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(63, 191, 63)"
    }, {
      "label": "Budgeted amount",
      "data": [60, 150, 20, 30],
      "type": "bar",
      "fill": false,
      "borderColor": "rgb(63, 65, 191)",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(63, 65, 191)"
    }]
  },
  "options": {
    "scales": {
      "yAxes": [{
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartjs-7" class="chartjs" width="770" height="385" style="display: block; width: 770px; height: 385px;"></canvas>
</body>
```

However mine currently appears like this.

[image: Stacked2]

Any ideas how to do this or if it is even possible with graphJS I can't seem to find a way to stack these against each other

Comment: Do you just want one bar and the label to display everything or do you want the bar/colours stacked too?

Comment: Stacked colours also. So a blue for budgeted, green for amound spent, red for anything over budget @George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `stacked: true` to `xAxes`:

```
"options": {
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [{
        "stacked": true,
      }],
      "yAxes": [{
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chartjs-7"), {
  "type": "bar",
  "data": {
    "labels": ["Petrol", "Food", "Kids Clubs", "Alcohol"],
    "datasets": [{
      "label": "Actual Spend",
      "data": [70, 100, 20, 29],
      "borderColor": "rgb(63, 191, 63)",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(63, 191, 63)"
    }, {
      "label": "Budgeted amount",
      "data": [60, 150, 20, 30],
      "type": "bar",
      "fill": false,
      "borderColor": "rgb(63, 65, 191)",
      "backgroundColor": "rgba(63, 65, 191)"
    }]
  },
  "options": {
    "scales": {
      "xAxes": [{
        "stacked": true,
      }],
      "yAxes": [{
        //"stacked": true,
        "ticks": {
          "beginAtZero": true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartjs-7" class="chartjs" width="770" height="385" style="display: block; width: 770px; height: 385px;"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: This does not do what is being aimed at here. The aim was to show a bit like a percentage bar. So the budgeted amount is 100, and the actual is 60, up to the 60 mark should be filled. This stacks both on top so it would show as 160 against the axsis. So if you look at Kids Clubs it fills up to 40 because actual is 20 and buget is 20, this bar should just show as full green

Comment: Accepting this answer, just needed to also changed stacked to false